# How to retrieve a value after second hyphen using mysql select query

Tags: mysql

Below I am using substring index within max attribute in select statement to get max value from a column. But below code works fine for single digits after second dash but it doesn't retrieve value for double digit values after second dash.

Below is the query what i am using

```
   select max(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pid,"-",-1)) from patient;
```

Values stored in column are of pattern as shown below

```
P-29082017-1,
P-29082017-2,
...
P-29082017-9,
P-29082017-10
```

The above query returns only single digit, i,e if i have 10 entries say pid from 1 to 10 listed in column, Value i am getting back from the above query is 9 and not 10

Please suggest where i am going wrong with the query

Comment: @Jens I don't think the OQ has more than one of these  `P-29082017-10` strings in any given row.

Comment: @O.Jones You are shure? Why the comma at the end? But maybe only bad formating

Answer (score 1):

I think your `max()` function is being evaluated in string context rather than numeric context. In string context, `9` comes after `10`.

So try this. It will turn `SUBSTRING()` output into numbers.

```
 SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pid,'-',-1) AS INT))
```

Comment: He can also try with `DECIMAL`.